# "Under the name of" OR "in the name of"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I want to ask that if there is a cheese product "paneera" in the market. Then what should I say?

1. Cheese is available **under the name of** paneera?

OR

2. Cheese is available **in the name of** paneera?

OR

3. Cheese is available **available as** paneera?

Answer (score 2):

[**under the name of**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/under%20the%20name%20(of)%20(someone/something)) specifies that something uses the name of/belongs to **a person**, while [**in the name of**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/in-the-name-of-sb-sth) indicates that something/someone is **representing** another thing/another person.  **available as** doesn't get its own dictionary entry, and is used in a variety of situations, ranging from [someone available to do something](https://www.cbssports.com/fantasy/baseball/news/astros-framber-valdez-available-as-reliever-this-weekend/), [an alternate name for something (usually preceded by **also**)](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZrALBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA100&lpg=PA100&dq=available%20as&source=bl&ots=i0XfIDynH2&sig=cQxph947LHMcjVymXp-olz4Vkzw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjZn7zm2c7dAhUD2o8KHZ7JBck4ChDoATABegQICBAB#v=onepage&q=available%20as&f=false), to [something available in another form](https://help.pottermore.com/hc/en-gb/articles/115005548789-Which-Pottermore-eBooks-are-available-as-Kindle-in-Motion-editions-).

None of the above can be used in your situation. Therefore, I'd suggest keeping it simple and use: **Paneera cheese is available**.

Comment: I agree that _in the name of_ means something different, but I see nothing wrong with using _under the name of_ in this case.

Comment: @ColinFine I agree. *Under the name of* is always fine. (I always *do* go under my own name . . .) It doesn't mean that you are impersonating somebody—just that that's the name you're using, for whatever reason.

Comment: My point was that _under the name of_ is in no way limited to a person.

Comment: It may not have been clear because of the formatting problems, but the question is about *asking* whether paneer is available, not explaining that paneer is available. The simplest way to ask is "Do you have any paneer cheese?"